# why does my clearInterval not clear the interval? - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, setinterval, clearinterval

I got two intervals, one is inside the other:

```
function start(start) {

    if (start) {
        firstInterval = setInterval(function () {

            console.log("firstInterval called")
            secondInterval = setInterval(function(){

                clearInterval(secondInterval)
                secondInterval = null
                console.log("secondInterval called")
            },1000)


        }, 1000)

    }else{

        clearInterval(firstInterval)
        firstInterval = null

        clearInterval(secondInterval)
        secondInterval = null

    }
}
```

the else block gets called when I press a "stop" button, the "firstInterval" gets cleared but the "secondInterval" keeps on logging "secondInterval called"

Why does this happen and how can I prevent this.

Comment: Because another `secondInterval` gets set before the previous has been triggered and thereby cleared itself. Since you only have one variable to store the `secondInterval` handle in, it gets overwritten and the handle to the previous one is lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `firstInterval` is creating multiple `secondInterval`s

Each time the `firstInterval` fires, it creates its own `secondInterval`. Only one of the `secondInterval`s gets cleared.

To fix this, change the first one to a `setTimeout`, so it only fires once.

Comment: But I need the firstInterval to loop, the code inside should get called every second until I hit "stop"

Comment: But I could use setTimeout on the second interval! Thank you so much, setTimeout solved it for me